# Getting the below error after installing @react-native-firebase/auth in my react native project. I am using react native CLI

Tags: reactjs, react-native

After installing @react-native-firebase/auth with npm, i did pod install under my ios folder. Pod install is successful. But after that when I am trying to run npx react-native run-ios, I am getting this error.

The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/piupaul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myShare-akplocsikdtwjdftkmfamcyweqnp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseAuth.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FIRUser.o /Users/piupaul/Documents/Work/myShare/myShare/ios/Pods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/User/FIRUser.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'FirebaseAuth' from project 'Pods')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue yesterday and just fixed it now. After many attempts doing pod install, use_modular_headers, and clearing out pod cache, it made me try removing firebase/auth based on your question! And it worked! App seems fine and can still use RNFB auth. I haven't deeply researched why but I have assumptions. But hey, it works. If you could provide a way to reproduce the error as well, we could try helping out. But, seems like this worked for me:

1. npm remove @react-native-firebase/app
2. npm remove @react-native-firebase/auth
3. cd ios
4. pod install
5. cd ..
6. npx react-native run-ios